# Is it possible to use a library with .NET 3.5 requirements in Unity 5.6.7f1?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I hava a game in Unity 5.6.7f1. Now I want to use a library but it requires .NET 3.5 or higher. Is it possible to use this library without using a higher Unity version?

More specifically, I want to use the Tincan library from http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCan.NET/. This library sends a HTTP-Post-Request to a DB that stores User Statements (i.e. UserX started the Game).
In a Higher Unity version (e.g. 2018.4.3f1) works fine but in Unity 5.6.7f1 doesn't.
I think it's because 5.6.7f1 doesn't support .NET 3.5

This is my first post so i hope i did everything right

Thanks a lot 
Zukahara

What I tried:

- Tested in Unity 2018.4.3f1 -> works well and copied the code in unity 5.6.7f1 -> getting an TlsException (see down below). Convert the Projekt vom 2018.4.3f1 to 5.6.7f1 -> the same
- Tried to install the IL2CPP for Unity 5.6.7f1 -> didn't make sense for me and don't followed that approach

I get this Error message:

TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates)
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 ()
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process ()
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg)
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
Rethrow as IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
Rethrow as WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ()

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with .NET version. `Invalid certificate received from server.`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Unity 5 supports Mono version 2 which is equivalent to .Net 3.5 but there are some limitations and the error log provided clearly shows a problem in connecting using TLS. I would recommend you check for the non-https version of URLs and see if it works or not.

> TLS support for .NET 3.5 and below varies per platform and there are
>   no guarantees on which features are supported.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I will give this a try

Comment: And is it possible to use a https version?